# String Matching in Shell

Tags: shell

I have file a file named as file.yaml with the below content :

```
SystemType=Secondary-HA
Hostname America
```

I have a shell script filter.sh:

```
echo "Enter systemType:"
read systemType
SYSTYPE=`grep systemType /home/oracle/file.yaml | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ SYSTYPE=Secondary-HA ]
then
    cat /home/oracle/file.yaml > /home/oracle/file2.txt
fi
hstname=`grep Hostname /home/oracle/file2.txt | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $hstname
```

Here I want to given the systemType only 'Secondary-HA' then only I should get the result as America. But as of now if I am giving the systemType 'Secondary', I am giving the same result as America. which I don't want. 
Please let know. I am bit new in shell scripting.

Comment: "Shell" meaning POSIX sh, or bash, or something else?

Comment: BTW, what this code is doing the way it's written right now is testing whether `SYSTYPE=Secondary-HA` is an empty string -- which, of course, it never is; it's always the exact same 20 characters.

Comment: (It's also very unclear to me, as a reader, exactly what the desired behavior is -- you partially specify two cases, but not clearly and completely. Describing what you want in English, rather with code you already know doesn't do what you want it to, is more likely to get an accurate answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that the shell is white-space sensitive in certain places, for example when splitting arguments. Thus,

```
if [ x=y ]
```

must be written as

```
if [ x = y ]
```

In addition, I have replaced the anti-pattern

```
grep xyz file | awk '{print $2}'
```

with the much less expensive pipe-less

```
awk '/xyz/ {print $2}' file
```

Next, awk splits at white-space by default, not by `=`. You would need to say `awk -F=` to split at `=`. I have also uppercased systemType to SystemType, since that's what you tell us is in your yaml file. Mate, you need to be careful if you want to be in programming.

Here is the result:

```
echo "Enter systemType:"
read systemType
SYSTYPE=$(awk -F= '/SystemType/ {print $2}' /home/oracle/file.yaml)
if [ "$SYSTYPE" = "$systemType" ]; then
    cp /home/oracle/file.yaml /home/oracle/file2.txt
fi
hstname=$(awk '/Hostname/ {print $2}' /home/oracle/file2.txt)
echo $hstname
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `awk -v patt="$systemType" '$0 ~ patt {print $2}'` -- hi just does understand that variable references require `$`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks; I have modified the "if" test accordingly. Hopefully that is closer to what the OP wants.